# Windows Server 2012 R2 + SQL Server cluster failover with 2 node

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, failovercluster, windows-clustering

Now i have 2 Servers on same network 1. Windows Server 2012 r2 and 2. Windows Server 2016.
i need to make both server run together i'm not sure and if the first node is down the second node can be continue running the SQL Server for my Systems So can anyone can suggest me about the solution how to do that 
Thank you forward.

Comment: Check the fail over [**cluster manager**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2672/managing-a-windows-and-sql-server-cluster-using-the-failover-cluster-manager-tool/) on the windows server.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not for IT questions.